Original source of the term "Atzmus" in Kabbalah
B"H
I know Chassidus and kabbalah often refers to the Atzmus (Essence of G-d). What is the original source of the idea?
I know the verse in the Torah mentions the bones, עַצְמ֥וֹת (Atzmos) of Yosef, Exodus 13:19. Is it where kabbalah gets the idea of Atzmus from?
What is the original primary source of the term Atzmus in kabbalah? Is it mentioned anywhere in Zohar?
While I know that Rambam mentions a similar concept אֲמִתַּת הִמָּצְאוֹ the Truth of His Being (Foundations of the Torah 1:1), I am specifically asking for the first source that uses the term Atzmus. Thanks
(The Wikipedia article mentioned only cites secondary sources. I'm not sure if those secondary sources cite the primary source)

The concept of Atzmus is mentioned in Emunot VDeot, and Moreh Nevuchim. It's also mentioned in Kabbalah, and in every generation it is explained better. The Shalah's use of the term is not the same as Rambam's, neither is it the same as the 7th Lubavitcher Rebbe, but it's one continuous explanation/revelation. As our minds expand and our education gets more abstract, our vessel gets wider and can capture more light, and we can get a deeper understanding of Atzmus.

@RabbiKaii are those the original sources? Where in the moreh nevuchim does it talk about it

@RabbiKaii I'm a fan of Rabbi nachman? This is news to me

Part 1, Chapter 52 onwards
